# PS4 GTA V Online v Sony Pulse wireless headset

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Is this correctable? I get the message: "Action is incompatible with your current headgear" when all I am trying to do is Salute, Jerk, Bro love, etc. (L3/R3 buttons) My character just shakes his head "NO" and the message comes up. I am using PS4, GTAV Online, (PS3) Sony Pulse Wireless Stereo Headset.

Answer (score 1):

By headgear the game means your character's mask or hat,not your headset.Take off your characters hat or mask and try again.

Comment: This is basically identical to the existing answer.

Comment: I feel this one elaborates more by explaining that headgear is your character's headgear, not **your** headset.

Answer (score 0):

Headgear: you're wearing something on your head that blocks the actions. Take off all masks, hats, etc. and try again